# How to create a chat app using TCP in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, swift5, tcpclient

I simply wants to pass a string from one phone to another (vice versa) using TCP connection. Hence, I have a few questions as I'm a bit confused.

1. Can this be achieved using two different simulators in two different mac machines ?
2. Can this be achieved using two different simulators in the same mac machine ?
3. If this can be done on simulators would replacing the IP of the mac would work with 8080 port ?

My partially completed code as bellow;

```
class NWTCPConnection: NSObject {
    var connection: NWConnection!

    func connectToTcp() {
        let PORT: NWEndpoint.Port = 8080
        let  ipAddress :NWEndpoint.Host = "192.168.8.133" //Machines IP
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "TCP Client Queue")
        
        let tcp = NWProtocolTCP.Options.init()
        tcp.noDelay = true
        let params = NWParameters.init(tls: nil, tcp: tcp)
        connection = NWConnection(to: NWEndpoint.hostPort(host: ipAddress, port: PORT), using: params)
        
        connection.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
            switch (newState) {
            case .ready:
                print("Socket State: Ready")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isConnected")
                self.sendMSG()
                self.receive()
            default:
                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isConnected")

                break
            }
        }
        connection.start(queue: queue)
    }



  func sendMSG() {
       print("send data")
       let message1 = "hello world"
       let content: Data = message1.data(using: .utf8)!
       connection.send(content: content, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
           if (NWError == nil) {
               print("Data was sent to TCP destination ")
               
           } else {
               print("ERROR! Error when data (Type: Data) sending. NWError: \n \(NWError!)")
           }
       })))
  }




 // How to trigger this ???
 func receive() {
  connection.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
    if (isComplete) {
            print("Receive is complete, count bytes: \(data!.count)")
        if (data != nil) {
                print(data!)
        } else {
            print("Data == nil")
        }
    }
 }

}
```

the moment I run the simulator and call the connectToTcp() I get the following error

```
nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
```

Comment: 2 is a yes, for the other 2 it is a likely, I have never tried it.